# Checking for Value in CopyFileEx flags

Tags: c, winapi

I have a DWORD dwCopyFlags which contains the copy flags of the function CopyFileEx.  Is there some way to parse dwCopyFlags to check if it contains a certain type of flag, such as COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS?

Comment: `if ( dwCopyFlags & COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS ) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flag is a value with a single bit set. You test for that bit being set in a flags variable using bitwise and, the `&` operator. Bitwise and returns a value that each bit set if and only that bit was set in both operands. So, since your flag has a single bit set, the test is simply `flag & flags != 0`.

With your variable names that becomes:

```
if (dwCopyFlags & COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS != 0)
    ....
```